# What is the file structure in SugarCRM deploy from Studio

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I am facing a problem with SugarCRM. I made a relationship and other changes from Studio and deployed them. However, my previously made changes from ModuleBuilder and custom changes within the /custom/modules directory vanish. Why is that?

I also have another question:

When I make changes and deploy from ModuleBuilder, SugarCRM distributes the copy of changes from the /custom/ModuleBuilder/packages directory. If I make changes and deploy from Studio then where does SugarCRM distribute the copy of changes?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing SugarCRM's Module Builder and Studio tools is dangerous, and it seems like you just found out why.

Building out a module in Module Builder is absoltuely the best practice, but once it's deployed, you'll want to *never* hit deploy again. The Deploy button wipes out anything in `/custom/Extension/modules/MyModule/Ext/` and `/custom/modules/MyModule` for your custom module NewModule. MyModule exactly where Studio puts it's changes, whether they're new fields, layouts, or relationships.

A great way to avoid this is to keep your system in version control. A simple `git init` works wonders, but you'll probably want to use a `.gitignore` file like [SugarCRM.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/SugarCRM.gitignore).

Another way to accommodate this is to keep a production and a staging server. That way you can be 100% sure that what you're trying to do works before you do it. This also lets you use Module Builder in the development system, then Publish the package, and install it in production. That way Production doesn't have the package in Module Builder, thus there is no Deploy Button to push.